# Store Procedure in Mysql: First try

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I was reading and trying to create procedure in mySql v5.5 using WorkBench software on windows machine.

my procedure code is:

```
create procedure GetMyFolderName ()
begin
Select foldername from `folder` f where f.folderid=10;
end
```

However when I run this code I got

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

I try to put `;` after END but still similar error, I tried lot of combination but didn't get it working as per this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

I infact try

```
Delimiter //;
create procedure GetMyFolderName ()
begin
    Select foldername from `folder` f where f.folderid=10;
end//
Delimiter ;
```

And still no result, always get that 1064 error? Any idea why.

Comment: `mYSql` - iT's BeAUtiFUl

Comment: :) .. now can you answer it please.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out this..

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMyFolderName ()
BEGIN
    Select foldername from folder f where f.folderid=10;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: this works, but it doesn't work under phpMyadmin, now it works when I try this query through PHP's mysqli/mysql library execute code... But it does work under workbench? Isn't the same query should work there ?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Delimiter //;
create procedure GetMyFolderName ()
begin
Select foldername from `folder` f where f.folderid=10;
end;//
Delimiter ;
```

Error is on end statement. you should use ';' at end of statement.